# How to use capybara with multiple forms in the one view with Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, capybara, minitest

I have a Rails 3.2 project using Minitest::Spec and Capybara.

My view contains multiple forms so I can either edit or delete the record. Sample code:

```
<%= simple_form_for @product do |f| %>  
  <fieldset>
  #all of my field code
    <div id="form-actions" class="span12 form-horizontal">
        <%= f.submit nil, :class => 'create-button', :id => 'update_product' %>
        <%= link_to 'Cancel', products_path, :class => 'btn' %>
     </div>
   </fieldset>    
<% end %>

  <% if !@product.new_record? %>
    <div id="form-actions" class="form-horizontal">
      <%= button_to "delete", @product, :confirm => "Are you sure?", :method=>:delete, :class=>'delete-button', :id => 'delete_product' %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

In my test if I call `click_on "update_product"` (the id of the update button) the delete action of the second form is called rather than the update action.

Answer (score 0):

You use wrong option on `f.submit` as

```
:html => {:id => 'update_product' }
```

You can't assign id here. So you can see the output is actually escaped html. These are pure  text and not real html.

```
{:id=&gt;&quot;update_product&quot;}
```

My suggestion:

Remove the option in submit form. Give it a name(value), say `f.submit 'Update'`. Also it's not necessary to assign ids within a form by yourself.

Then ask Capybara to `click_button 'Update'`. He can find it without any problem.

**Add**

If you want Capybara to click by id instead of text, add `#` before it to read as  `click_button '#update-product'`.

However I do recommend you to assign whatever a value(text) to that button, and ask Capybara to click it.  Set the button to `nil` or blank is really not a convention and not nice.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. By highlighting my incorrect implementation with `f.submit` I have found the correct way to include the id is just to use `, :id => "update_product"`. This then appears correctly in the html as `id="update_product" name="commit" type="submit" `. However, when I run my test for update it still executes the delete method. I would prefer not to use `f.submit 'Update'` because the form is a partial that can be used for both 'Add Product' and 'Update Product'.

Comment: @Marklar, please update your code in question after your revising.

Comment: I have updated the code and original question to more clearly reflect the current problem.

Comment: Thanks again for your help. I can't find anywhere in the Capybara documentation that states to use `#` for id instead of text, but I tried it anyway with the same result `Unable to find button "#update_product"`. Seeing as this didn't work I tried replacing the `nil` of the button with "Update Product", however clicking this does not give an error but again calls the DELETE action rather than the UPDATE action.